# UtteranceProgressListener not being Called even after passing hashmap String(read before flagging as duplicate)

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to put an onUtteranceProgressListener on tts. I've gone through other relevant questions on stackoverflow and followed them. But even after passing utterance id string through Hashmap or Bundle(Since Hashmap is deprecated after api21), utteranceProgressListener isn't getting called. I've used toasts to verify, but there were no toast outputs. I'm getting the audio output, but unable to get the progressListener work on it.

```
@Override
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            myTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    Toast.makeText(InvisibleActivity.this,"listener Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    if (utteranceId.equals("utteranceId")) {
                        myTTS.stop();
                        Toast.makeText(InvisibleActivity.this,"mytts stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {

                }
            });
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry,Text To speech not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"utteranceId");

        myTTS.speak(outText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle,null);
        chan();
    }
```

The Hashmap Code (with deprecated speak()) I've used, is:

```
HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"utteranceId");
myTTS.speak(outText,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
```

I've tried both `QUEUE_ADD` and `QUEUE_FLUSH` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it works on another thread.
You need to use the runOnUiThread to make it work:

```
tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String s) {

                final String keyword = s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String s) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Make sure that this method is called before the `speak` method.